# Gradle Error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to import a project to eclipse (which was getting build using intellijide on another computer), but could not succeed using gradle.

I can not get the system see some of the imports (for some autogenerated files). Full output is as follows, but the first error I get is
`[Daemon worker Thread 8] ERROR o.a.i.p.ModelValidator:77 - org.androidannotations.annotations.Bean can only be used on an element annotated with @org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean`
and I do not have the source code for ModelValidator.
I searched for the error but couldn't find anything that helpes solving the problem I have.

Does anyone have any suggestions to solve the problem?
Regards
Orhan

Here is the output I receive

```
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app
Gradle User Home: Use default defined by Gradle
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 2.2
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Gradle Tasks: build

Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBoxDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkBoxDebugManifest
:app:preBoxReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preClientDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preClientReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareChAcraAcra485Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlockLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidUtilsUtilsLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCsipsimpleUiComCsipsimpleUiSipHomeLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJourneyappsZxingAndroidEmbedded340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgXwalkXwalk_core_library_beta164542119Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareBoxDebugDependencies
:app:compileBoxDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileBoxDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateBoxDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateBoxDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeBoxDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateBoxDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateBoxDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeBoxDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processBoxDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processBoxDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateBoxDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processBoxDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileBoxDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileBoxDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileBoxDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:collectBoxDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageAllBoxDebugClassesForMultiDex UP-TO-DATE
:app:shrinkBoxDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:createBoxDebugMainDexClassList UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexBoxDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageBoxDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:zipalignBoxDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleBoxDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkClientDebugManifest
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2501Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72501Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2501Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2501Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareClientDebugDependencies
:app:compileClientDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileClientDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateClientDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateClientDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeClientDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateClientDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateClientDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeClientDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processClientDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processClientDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateClientDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processClientDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileClientDebugJavaWithJavac
09:49:26.861 [Daemon worker Thread 8] INFO  o.a.i.AndroidAnnotationProcessor:88 - Initialize AndroidAnnotations 4.1.0 with options {resourcePackageName=com.maar, androidManifestFile=E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\client\debug\AndroidManifest.xml, logLevel=INFO, trace=true, logAppenderConsole=true}
09:49:26.958 [Daemon worker Thread 8] INFO  o.a.i.AndroidAnnotationProcessor:108 - Plugins loaded: [REST-Spring, OrmLite]
09:49:27.108 [Daemon worker Thread 8] INFO  o.a.i.AndroidAnnotationProcessor:121 - Start processing for 28 annotations on 148 elements
09:49:27.597 [Daemon worker Thread 8] INFO  o.a.i.AndroidAnnotationProcessor:164 - AndroidManifest.xml found: AndroidManifest [applicationPackage=com.maar.mobile, componentQualifiedNames=[com.maar.MainActivity_, com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity, org.acra.dialog.CrashReportDialog, com.maar.client.ServerConnectionService_, org.acra.sender.SenderService, com.maar.db.yeni.SchedularReceiver], permissionQualifiedNames=[android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE], applicationClassName=com.maar.MaarApp_, libraryProject=false, debugabble=false, minSdkVersion=17, maxSdkVersion=-1, targetSdkVersion=25]
09:49:27.600 [Daemon worker Thread 8] INFO  o.a.i.r.ProjectRClassFinder:51 - Found project R class: com.maar.R
09:49:27.694 [Daemon worker Thread 8] INFO  o.a.i.r.AndroidRClassFinder:45 - Found Android class: android.R
09:49:27.801 [Daemon worker Thread 8] INFO  o.a.i.p.ModelValidator:46 - Validating elements
09:49:27.843 [Daemon worker Thread 8] ERROR o.a.i.p.ModelValidator:77 - org.androidannotations.annotations.Bean can only be used on an element annotated with @org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean
09:49:27.844 [Daemon worker Thread 8] WARN  o.a.i.p.ModelValidator:88 - Element scenarioRunner invalidated by BeanHandler
09:49:27.923 [Daemon worker Thread 8] INFO  o.a.i.p.TimeStats:81 - Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 815 ms], [Extract Manifest = 435 ms], [Find R Classes = 202 ms], [Extract Annotations = 53 ms], 
09:49:27.924 [Daemon worker Thread 8] INFO  o.a.i.AndroidAnnotationProcessor:137 - Finish processing
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\client\com\maar\ui\UIItemGenerator.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import com.maar.ApplicationSettings_;
               ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: package com.maar
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\client\com\maar\ui\UIItemGenerator.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    ApplicationSettings_ applicationSettings;
    ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: class UIItemGenerator
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\base\com\maar\ProjectReader.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
import com.maar.ApplicationSettings_;
               ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: package com.maar
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\base\com\maar\db\DatabaseHelper.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
import com.maar.ApplicationSettings_;
               ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: package com.maar
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\base\com\maar\ProjectReader.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
    ApplicationSettings_ applicationSettings;
    ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: class ProjectReader
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\base\com\maar\db\DatabaseHelper.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    ApplicationSettings_ applicationSettings;
    ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: class DatabaseHelper
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\base\com\maar\db\yeni\SchedularReceiver.java:12: error: package com.maar.box.scenarios does not exist
import com.maar.box.scenarios.ScenarioRunner;
                             ^
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\base\com\maar\db\yeni\SchedularReceiver.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    ScenarioRunner scenarioRunner;
    ^
  symbol:   class ScenarioRunner
  location: class SchedularReceiver
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\base\com\maar\ui\fragments\ContentFragment.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
    ApplicationSettings_ applicationSettings;
    ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: class ContentFragment
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\client\com\maar\MaarApp.java:212: error: cannot find symbol
    ApplicationSettings_ applicationSettings;
    ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: class MaarApp
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\client\com\maar\MainActivity.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
    ApplicationSettings_ applicationSettings;
    ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: class MainActivity
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\client\com\maar\ui\fragments\MainFragment.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
import com.maar.ApplicationSettings_;
               ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: package com.maar
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\client\com\maar\ui\fragments\ProjectListFragment.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
import com.maar.ApplicationSettings_;
               ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: package com.maar
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\client\com\maar\ui\fragments\MainFragment.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
    ApplicationSettings_ applicationSettings;
    ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: class MainFragment
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\client\com\maar\ui\fragments\LoginFragment.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    ApplicationSettings_ applicationSettings;
    ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: class LoginFragment
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\client\com\maar\ui\fragments\ProjectListFragment.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
    ApplicationSettings_ applicationSettings;
    ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: class ProjectListFragment
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\client\com\maar\client\ServerConnectionService.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
    ApplicationSettings_ applicationSettings;
    ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: class ServerConnectionService
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\client\com\maar\ui\components\SettingsView.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    ApplicationSettings_ applicationSettings;
    ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationSettings_
  location: class SettingsView
Note: Resolve log file to E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\build\generated\source\apt\client\androidannotations.log
Note: Initialize AndroidAnnotations 4.1.0 with options {resourcePackageName=com.maar, androidManifestFile=E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\client\debug\AndroidManifest.xml, logLevel=INFO, trace=true, logAppenderConsole=true}
Note: Plugins loaded: [REST-Spring, OrmLite]
Note: Start processing for 28 annotations on 148 elements
Note: AndroidManifest.xml found: AndroidManifest [applicationPackage=com.maar.mobile, componentQualifiedNames=[com.maar.MainActivity_, com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity, org.acra.dialog.CrashReportDialog, com.maar.client.ServerConnectionService_, org.acra.sender.SenderService, com.maar.db.yeni.SchedularReceiver], permissionQualifiedNames=[android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE], applicationClassName=com.maar.MaarApp_, libraryProject=false, debugabble=false, minSdkVersion=17, maxSdkVersion=-1, targetSdkVersion=25]
Note: Found project R class: com.maar.R
Note: Found Android class: android.R
Note: Validating elements
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\base\com\maar\db\yeni\SchedularReceiver.java:31: error: org.androidannotations.annotations.Bean can only be used on an element annotated with @org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean
    @Bean
    ^
E:\Folder\REPOSITORY\svn_repository\UserInterface\Android\MaarProject\Maarbox3\app\src\main\java\base\com\maar\db\yeni\SchedularReceiver.java:32: warning: Element scenarioRunner invalidated by BeanHandler
    ScenarioRunner scenarioRunner;
                   ^
Note: Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 815 ms], [Extract Manifest = 435 ms], [Find R Classes = 202 ms], [Extract Annotations = 53 ms], 
Note: Finish processing
09:49:28.297 [Daemon worker Thread 8] INFO  o.a.i.AndroidAnnotationProcessor:121 - Start processing for 0 annotations on 0 elements
09:49:28.300 [Daemon worker Thread 8] INFO  o.a.i.p.TimeStats:81 - Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 3 ms], 
09:49:28.302 [Daemon worker Thread 8] INFO  o.a.i.AndroidAnnotationProcessor:137 - Finish processing
Note: Start processing for 0 annotations on 0 elements
Note: Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 3 ms], 
Note: Finish processing
19 errors
1 warning
:app:compileClientDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileClientDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 53.263 secs
```